# Docker container .NET Core framework doesn't exist

Tags: docker, .net-core

Every time there is an update to the .NET 6 framework, I get something like the following error when trying to update a Docker container:

```
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.12' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/
The following frameworks were found:
  6.0.11 at [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.12&arch=x64&rid=debian.11-x64
```

I have only made a minor code change and am trying to re-deploy my service. I am not adding/updating dependencies. The problem always goes away the next day. How can I get around/prevent this error from happening?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["src/Services/Orders/KapSys.Orders.Sync/KapSys.Orders.Sync.csproj", "src/Services/Orders/KapSys.Orders.Sync/"]
RUN dotnet restore "src/Services/Orders/KapSys.Orders.Sync/KapSys.Orders.Sync.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Services/Orders/KapSys.Orders.Sync"
RUN dotnet build "KapSys.Orders.Sync.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "KapSys.Orders.Sync.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "KapSys.Orders.Sync.dll"]
```

Edit: I had initially thought that installing the latest version of runtime on my machine had solved the issue, but the error occurred as of .net 6.0.14 and updating my runtimes did not solve the issue.

Comment: Can you please share the DOCKERFILE's few lines where you are referencing .NET 6 base image?

Comment: @AnkushJain  docker file added

Comment: The above error says `The following frameworks were found:`. From where you copied this error?

Comment: @Ankush It was from portainer. The service deploys but failes to start due to that error

Answer (score 0):

Removing all my old docker images seems to have fixed the issue.

It looks like maybe docker was using a cached image of .netcore image and so didn't have the updated version of .net when deploying despite building on the newest version.